# Calling NXC code and library from F#

Tags: c, f#, nxc

There is a special function used in NXC called ReadColorSensorEx():

```
int ReadSensorColorEx   (   const byte &    port,
int &   colorval,
unsigned int &  raw[],
unsigned int &  norm[],
int &   scaled[] 
)
```

But I cannot use exactly the same function in F# libraries.

`norm[]` type is for normalized color values, and `scaled[]` variable is scaled color values fetched by NXT Color Sensor.

But in MonoBrickFirmware.dll library which is used by F#, I couldn't find any way to fetch these two values.

NXC is not a .NET based programming language. NXC is a language developed for programming Lego NXT bricks.

NXC is using a special library for ReadColorSensorEx() function.

Is there a way to merge NXC code and it's libraries with F#?

Comment: If the library is written in .net, then it is available in F#.  Can you be more specific about what you're looking for and give an example of how you're trying to use it in F#?

Comment: Okay mydogisbox, I'll edit my question right now.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666573/readsensorcolorex-function-in-nxc-and-its-conversion-in-monobrickfirmware-lib

Comment: John Palmer, the difference is; here, I'm asking whether is it possible to merge NXC with F# on the same environment, but the other question is asking how can I fetch NXT Color Sensor raw, normalized, and scaled color values as 4 bytes of arrays via using MonoBrickUsing library in F#. I couldn't find a way to do that, that's why I'm asking this question.